# Lucene CustomScoreQuery does not pass value from FunctionQuery's FieldSource

Tags: java, lucene

If i understand correctly from the [Lucene Java Doc Page](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/CustomScoreQuery.html#isStrict()), setting a `CustomScoreQuery` instance to strict should pass a `FunctionQuery`'s `FieldSource` value without modifications (like normalization) to `valSrcScore` of `CustomScoreProvider` in the method `public float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore)`.
Thus, I thought, that I get exactly the float value back, that is stored within a `FloatSourceField` of a document.

But this seems not the case when the amount of indexed data gets larger. Here I have a minimal example showing what I mean:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.*;
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;
import org.apache.lucene.queries.*;
import org.apache.lucene.queries.function.FunctionQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.queries.function.valuesource.FloatFieldSource;
import org.apache.lucene.search.*;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import java.io.IOException;
public class CustomScoreTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RAMDirectory index = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST, new StandardAnalyzer());
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(index, config);

        // prepare dummy text
        String text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) text += "abc ";

        // add dummy docs
        for (int i = 0; i <25000; i++) {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new FloatField("number", i * 100f, Field.Store.YES));
            doc.add(new TextField("text", text, Field.Store.YES));
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
        writer.close();

        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        Query q1 = new TermQuery(new Term("text", "abc"));
        CustomScoreQuery q2 = new CustomScoreQuery(q1, new FunctionQuery(new FloatFieldSource("number"))) {
            protected CustomScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider(AtomicReaderContext ctx) throws IOException {
                return new CustomScoreProvider(ctx) {
                    public float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore) throws IOException {
                        float diff = Math.abs(valSrcScore - searcher.doc(doc).getField("number").numericValue().floatValue());
                        if (diff > 0) throw new IllegalStateException("diff: " + diff);
                        return super.customScore(doc, subQueryScore, valSrcScore);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        // In strict custom scoring, the part does not participate in weight normalization.
        // This may be useful when one wants full control over how scores are modified, and
        // does not care about normalising by the  part
        q2.setStrict(true);

        // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: diff: 1490700.0
        searcher.search(q2, 10);
    }
}
```

As noted within this sample, an Exception gets thrown because because `valSrcScore` differs a lot from the actual value stored in the "number" Field of the document.

But when I reduce the numbers of indexed dummy documents to, say 2500, it works as expected and i get exactly the value with 0 difference to the value in the "number" Field.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of lucene are you running? one possibility maybe as your index size grows the `AtomicReaderContext` should be replaced with `LeafReaderContext`. Just a hypothesis

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With the new current version of Lucene the problem is now gone and the code works as I did expect it wo work.... so the IllegalStateException is not thrown and diff equals 0 as it should be :)